# having a regex replacing across lines, retain the newlines?

Tags: regex, linux, sed, grep

I'd like to have a substitute or print style command with a regex working across lines. And lines retained.

```
$ echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\ng' | tr -d '\n' | grep -or 'b.*f'
bcdef
```

or

```
$ echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\ng' | tr -d '\n' | sed -r 's|b(.*)f|y\1z|'
aycdezg
```

i'd like to use grep or sed because i'd like to know what people would've done before awk or perl ..

would they not have?  was .* not available? had they no other equivalent?

to possibly modify some input with a regex that spans across lines, and print it to stdout or output to a file, *retaining the lines*.

Comment: you could use pcgrep (in Linux) to grep with Perl-compatible regular expressions.

Comment: @ring bearer  that's nice, but as I said what did people do before perl and so, before pcregrep?

Comment: @ring bearer you mean pcregrep. you made a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
$ echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\ng' | sed ':a;$s/b\([^f]*\)f/y\1z/;N;ba'
a
y
c
d
e
z
g
```

It accumulates *all* the lines then does the replacement. It looks for the first "f". If you want it to look for the last "f", change `[^f]` to `.`.

Note that this may make use of features added to [`sed`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) *after* [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) or [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) became available (AWK has been around a *looong* time).

**Edit:**

To do a multi-line `grep` requires only a little modification:

```
$ echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\ng' | sed ':a;$s/^[^b]*\(b[^f]*f\)[^f]*$/\1/;N;ba'
b
c
d
e
f
```

Comment: @barlop: Please see my edited answer for a multi-line "grep -o".

Comment: That is brilliant.  What about the grep example? I suppose grep can't do it? But I suppose in sed that one is easier, to print between b and f, any character [a-z].  So of course not -n '/b/,/f/p'.

Comment: that's excellent. i didn't expect the "grep version" to be a bit longer.. very interesting

Comment: @barlop: Yes, `sed -n '/b/,/f/p'` works and is much shorter, obviously, and it outputs all "b-f" groups. However, the version that I showed can be easily modified to span from the first "b" to the last "f" or the last "b" to the next "f" or the last "f". So it has greater versatility.

Comment: yep, was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` can match across newlines through the use of its `N` command. For example, the following `sed` command will replace `bar` followed a `newline` followed by `foo` with `###`:

```
$ echo -e "foo\nbar\nbaz\nqux" | sed 'N;s/bar\nbaz/###/;P;D'
foo
###
qux
```

1. The `N` command will append the next input line to the current pattern space separated by an embedded newline (`\n`)
2. The `P` command will print the current pattern space up to and including the first embedded newline.
3. The `D` command will delete up to and including the first embedded newline in the pattern space. It will also start next cycle but skip reading from the input if there is still data in the pattern space.

Through the use of these 3 commands, you can essentially do any sort of `s` command replacement looking across N-lines.

#### Edit

If your question is how can I remove the need for `tr` in the two examples above and just use `sed` then here you go:

```
$ echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\ng' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g;y/ag/yz/'
ybcdefz
```

Comment: How would you do that for this? 'cos that method you mention doesn't seem to do it for this $ echo -e "a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\ng" | sed -r 'N;s/a(.*)g/y\1z/;P;D'

Comment: @barlop what do you expect the output to be from `echo -e "a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\ng" | sed -r 'N;s/a(.*)g/y\1z/;P;D'` ?

Comment: @SiegeX the same as the input but with a and g changed to y and z respectively. similar kind of thing to the example in my question.

Comment: @SiegeX  No in that added edit you haven't retained the newlines.

Comment: @SiegeX Do you understand what I mean?  I want abcdefg each letter on a new line as fed in in the input.  I want to do a replace with a regex that spans across lines. And I want to retain the new lines that were in the input.

Comment: @barlop Looks like Dennis got what you wanted.  In the future, it would be beneficial if you actually provide the output you are looking for, rather than try to simply describe it.  Leaves less room for interpretation and you get the right answer in a faster manner.

Comment: @SiegeX I think you originally commented with a general remark that you didn't know what I meant, you left it at that , that comment went, and you tried to answer, or if that comment wasn't yours, you could've made it, 'cos with asking the right questions and stating what wasn't clear, we could've discussed and I could've clarified it for you.  Nevertheless, I was clear enough that it looks a bit like everybody else interpreted me correctly including the first people except they just suggested solutions in perl  or pcregrep

Comment: @barlop I'm not trying to be argumentative.  However, I think you will find that putting a statement down that says "How do I get something that looks like <this> using only `sed`" and then actually put in code what <this> is, you'll find it will pay dividends with much less typing than trying to describe it.  It's just a suggestion from experience in both answering and asking questions here.  You are, of course, free to completely ignore it.  BTW, the `perl` answer gives the same (incorrect) answer as my first attempt. Unless there was some other `perl` answer that was since deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Proven tools to the rescue.

```
echo -e "foo\nbar\nbaz\nqux" | perl -lpe 'BEGIN{$/=""}s/foo\nbar/###/'
```

Comment: that's nice to know, but I did ask what did people do before perl..how would people have done it before perl